Differentiating between JWE and JWS when requesting resource
JWE and JWS both have the mime-types application/jose and application-jose+json assigned to them (see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#section-9 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-26#section-9.2.1).
That's all fine when receiving a message from a server, you can look at the content and see what you're dealing with.
But how would you go about having an endpoint from which you want to request either JWS or JWE? Since the mime-type is the same, you cannot use that as Accept header.
Can we use a suffix? Like: application/jose+jws
Or maybe a parameter? Like: application/jose; encrypted
